# What does the "a" at the end of my SQL query mean?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT MIN(id),
       MAX(id)
FROM  (SELECT film_id,
              COUNT(id) AS id
       FROM   screenings
       GROUP  BY film_id) a;
```

Comment: It is an alias for your subquery (SELECT film_id, COUNT(id) AS id FROM screenings GROUP BY film_id)

Comment: And it's a good argument for using `AS` for clarity, and for avoiding useless alias names. [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 3):

It means the dialect of SQL you're using (I think this may even be standard) requires that every subquery in the `FROM` by given an alias, even if that alias is not required anywhere else in the query. Of course, you *could* use the alias now it's defined:

```
SELECT MIN(a.id),MAX(a.id)
FROM
    (SELECT film_id, COUNT(id) AS id FROM screenings GROUP BY film_id) a;
```

But it's not usually necessary if it's clear where each column is coming from (as it is here with only one data source in the `FROM`).

Comment: FWIW, it is standard in SQL that a derived table must have a correlation name (aka table alias).

Answer (score 1):

The **a** that comes in the last of your query is an **alias**
it is a temporary name and can be use for column and table also.
In your query, you are trying to fetch min id and max id from sub query.

For more research about alias [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The terminology for the query in your example is a *derived table*.

The `select..from screenings` is producing what is known as a *derived table*, and your outer `select` is using it in the context of consuming its resultset as if it were a table in its own right - and the standard SQL syntax requires it is given an alias by which to identify it, even though in this case it's the only "table".

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be careful of is that the naming in the subselect is confusing.  You have `COUNT(id) AS id`, but a better name for that count would be something like `num_screenings`, because it's counting the number of screenings that the given `film_id` appeared at.

Subselects can often be clearly written as a CTE (common table expression). This makes them easier to understand because they are in small self-contained segments.

So, if we combine these three changes:

- Changing the subselect to a CTE
- Use the descriptive name `screening_counts` instead of `a`
- Change the `COUNT(id) AS id` to `AS num_screenings`

we get this that is much clearer:

```
WITH screening_counts AS (
    SELECT film_id, COUNT(id) AS num_screenings
    FROM screenings
    GROUP BY film_id
)
SELECT
MIN(num_screenings) AS min_screenings,
MAX(num_screenings) AS max_screenings
FROM screening_counts;
```